# How do you install GHC into Cygwin or point Cygwin to GHC?

Tags: haskell, installation, cygwin, bash

I attempted to point the Cygwin installer to http://haskell.org/ghc/cygwin, but the installer was unable to find setup.ini.sig. If possible, how could I alternatively edit my .bashrc to reference an installation made using the setup binaries in C:/ghc/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I installed the Windows version of GHC, added its binaries location to my PATH environment variable, I was able to run it from Cygwin's BASH just fine.  I've never attempted to install or compile GHC on Cygwin itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just add --no-verify to setup.exe which means

```
Don't verify setup.ini signatures
```

http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.cli